# An efficient way to check an IP address if it is a proxy of any sort?

Tags: proxy, geolocation, ip, ip-address, tor

How to check an IP address if it is a proxy of some sort (including TOR and possibly TOR alternatives)?

Any ideas about an elegant and reliable way? May be some online listing, tool, service, local method also an option?

P.S. I'm asking this, because I am kind of baffled whether to scan for specific ports in attempt to be serviced, or just rely on some online listings/dnsbl about TOR nodes, or both, or may be there is more universal approach because there may be TOR alternatives also? I've seen at least one.

Comment: Note: First I asked this question in serverfault.com, but moderators there say it isn't the correct website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the TOR list here:

[TOR (The Onion Router) Servers - IP List](http://proxy.org/tor.shtml)

or here: [Torstatus](http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/)

You'll have to scan every port and attempt to make a connection through it for your other part of the question, a proxy can serve on any port at all. So not, it's not really possible.

Comment: Ye. That's what I was thinking too, but wanted to make sure, because have little experience with this particular problem. Thank you. And thank you for the TOR status references.

Comment: if you are concerned with incoming traffic via proxy them some will set a header noting they are forwarding traffic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For